# Greedy algorithm is returning quanities too large for small values, but not larger values

Tags: c, while-loop, greedy

I'm writing a greedy algorithm (that has already caused me many headaches) that outputs the smallest number of coins that can be used for some monetary value, and I finally got code I was happy with, or so I thought. When inputting the value `.41`, I'm returned `4 coins` which is correct - however, the input `.01` returns `2 coins` and I have no idea why.

```
// declare variable change_owed, num_coins, and input globally
float change_owed = 0;
float dollars;
int cents;
int num_coins;

int main(void)
{
    // makes sure the input is non-negative
    do
    {
        dollars = get_float("Change owed:\n");
        cents = round(dollars * 100);
    }
    while(cents <= 0);

    // begin checking 


        while(cents - 25 >= 0) // quarters
        {
            num_coins++; // number of coins used, to be printed later, is incremented
            cents = cents - 25; // coin is subtracted from total
        }
        while(cents - 10 >= 0) // dimes
        {
            num_coins++;
            cents = cents >= 10;
        }   
        while(cents - 5 >= 0) // nickels
        {
            num_coins++;
            cents = cents - 5;
        } 
        while(cents >= 0) // pennies
        {
            num_coins++;
            cents = cents - 1;
        } 

    printf("%i coins\n", num_coins);
}
```

Comment: Try printing `cents` at the end of your program. What do you expect it to be? What is it?

Comment: Consider rewriting your while conditions to `while (cents >= 5)` which is more readable, and is the same

Comment: @MFisherKDX I want it to be `0`, right? I'm trying to whittle it down to no remainder, and that's what I got when I added that print.

Comment: Also, consider using this, which is shorter and nicer: `cents -= 5;`

Comment: Correct. You expect it to be zero. But when you input "0.01" you will see the cents is actually "-1" at the at the end of your program.

Comment: Also. You'll want to learn to use a debugger. This is a useful skill and will help you going forward.

Comment: You have a typo when handling dimes:  `cents = cents >= 10;` should be `cents = cents - 10;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you haven't initialized *num_coins*

```
int num_coins = 0;
```

Is there any reason why you are using while loops? integer arithmetic will do the same easier. Since *cents* is an int, dividing it by another int will return just the integer part (effectively rounded down).

```
num_coins = cents / 25; // returns the integer part, count of quarters
                        // This is an alternative to initialization
cents %= 25; // modulus operator returns the remainder
num_coins = num_coins + cents / 10; // count of dimes
cents %= 10;
num_coins = num_coins + cents / 5; // count of nickles
cents %= 5;
num_coins += cents; // cents must equal number of pennies required.
```

OK, I haven't tested the above code, so there may be some errors, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Main problem (off by one coin):

```
while(cents >= 0) // pennies
```

should be

```
while (cents - 1 >= 0) // or even better: while (cents >= 1)
```

---

Also, there is a typo:

```
cents = cents >= 10;
```

should be

```
cents = cents - 10; // or even better: cents -= 10;
```

Comment: Wow, I am an idiot. Thanks! Maybe one day I won't be a bumbling idiot.

Comment: @JohnAllison Everyone has a start. And even when one is not a starter anymore, we all do silly mistakes from time to time ;-)

Comment: Hey. It's fine. Nobody except Chuck Norris writes code correctly the first time for anything but small programs. Testing and debugging is part of the process of software development. [And it's not even the last step. Even after debugging, testing, and releasing code, it still has to be maintained.]